# How to read data from a database by chunk in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

In dplyr, if `tbl` is a table in a database then `head(tbl)` gets translated into

```sql
select
  *
from
  tbl
limit 6
```

but there doesn't seem to be a way to use the `offset` keyword to read data in chunks. E.g. the equivalent of

```sql
select
  *
from
  tbl
limit 6 offset 5
```

doesn't seem possible with `dplyr`. In `dbplyr`, there is a `do` function to let you choose a `chunk_size` to bring back data chunk-by-chunk.

Is that the only way to do it in R? The solution doesn't have to in `dplyr` or the `tidyverse`.

Comment: Have you tried the `DBI` package? That would let you send normal queries to the DB rather than being limited to what `dbplyr` have translated for you. 
[see here](https://db.rstudio.com/dbi/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to construct your own offset function. This assumes your database supports it, and the function is unlikely to be transferable to databases of other types.

Something like the following:

```
offset_head = function(table, num, offset){

  # get connection
  db_connection = table$src$con

  sql_query = build_sql(con = db_connection,
                      sql_render(table),
                      "\nLIMIT ", num,
                      "\nOFFSET ", offset
  )

  return(tbl(db_connection, sql(sql_query)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this in `dbplyr` is based on the addition of a reference/ID column:

```
my_tbl = tbl(con, "table_name")

for(i in 1:100){
  sub_tbl = my_tbl %>% filter(ID %% 100 == i)

  # further processing using 'sub_tbl'
  ...
}
```

If you add a row number to your dataset, then your filter could be replaced by `filter(LowerBound < row_number & row_number < UpperBound)`.